# SSL self signed certificates

Tags: http, ssl, https, certificate, signing

Can I purchase a single SSL certificate for domain A and sign all of my other domains with the domain A as reference.

Will it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for wildcard certificates.  Issuing a cert for *.mydomain.com would be valid for sub1.mydomain.com, sub2.mydomain.com, etc.

If you're looking to get a cert for mydomain.com and use that to generate a cert for otherdomain.com, that won't work.

FYI, wildcard certs are more considerably more expensive from what I remember.

EDIT:
Rereading your question, you want to do second option, and no, you can't do that.  You'll wind up with an invalid cert and most browsers put up giant warning signs that the cert isn't from a trusted source.  It will reference your cert for domain A as a trusted signer, which it is NOT, even though it WAS issued by a trusted signer further up the chain.  If what you wanted to do was possible, the entire trusted signer/TLS infrastructure would be useless.  (The utility of basic TLS as a verification that you're dealing with whom you think your dealing is debatable since it's trivial/inexpensive to get a cert.  Hence the existence of [Extended Validation Certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate).)

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can install those certificates. However just as with self-signed certificates the main problem is that they cannot be validated by browsers due to a broken verification chain.

In short: it won't work as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. The certificate for SSL is issued with specific allowed usage (which is encoded in the certificate). This does not includes signing other certificates.

Consequently though you technically will be able to sign certificates for other domains using the key of certificate A, such signed certificates will not be validated right and will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can not sign further certificates from your certificate. Otherwise you could sign somethign like www.paypal.com under your own legitimate SSL certificate - This was demonstrated as possible via a MITM attack at a blackhat conference but this has since been rendered no possible.

However you can get Multi-Domain certificates. These certificates allow you to include additional domains in the SAN field (Subject Alternative Name). So the certificate is generated for a single domain and the additional domains are added during the enrollment process with your SSL provider. You will need to verify ownership of each domain you request.

These certificates allow you to host multiple FQDN on a single IP with one SSL certificate.

In addition there are also wildcard certificates but these only let you secure *.domain.com with a single certificate.